# Sorting strings separated by commas within field using Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, table, sorting

In ArcGIS 10.4.1, I am using the Python Parser of the Field Calculator. My Python knowledge is limited.

I would like to recalculate a field of strings that are separated by commas so that they are ordered numerically. Say I have "3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1" and I would like it to be "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6".

Would it be possible to have a reverse sort?

I would like to apply the sorted values to new field, but I could also live with the sorted values in the original field.

Comment: Have you searched [so] for a Python code snippet that illustrates how to sort a string of comma separated values?

Comment: I haven't yet, but am looking now. Thanks for your edits and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this link for python code that does this with string values](http://pythonfiddle.com/sort-comma-delimited-string/).  To translate that to the Field Calculator and adjust it to deal with the spaces in your number list and to sort as integers numerically do the following Field Calculator settings:

Parser: Python

Code Block: Enabled

Pre-Logic Code Block:

```
def sortGroup(str):
    arr = str.split(', ')
    arr = sorted(arr, key=int)
    return ', '.join(str(i) for i in arr)
```

FieldYouAreCalculating:
sortGroup(!FieldContainingNumberList!)

To reverse the sort change arr = sorted(arr, key=int) to arr = sorted(arr, key=int, reverse=True)